# Show that $\varphi(\langle n, k\rangle) = \frac{1}{2}(n+k+1)(n+k)+n $ is injective

Tags: functions

How to show that the following function is an injective function?

$ \varphi : \mathbb{N}\times \mathbb{N} \rightarrow \mathbb{N} \\
\varphi(\langle n, k\rangle) = \frac{1}{2}(n+k+1)(n+k)+n$

I'm starting with $ \frac{1}{2}(a+b+1)(a+b)+a = \frac{1}{2}(c+d+1)(c+d)+c$, but how am I supposed to show from this equality that $\langle a, b\rangle = \langle c, d\rangle$, where $\langle a, b\rangle \in \mathbb{N}\times \mathbb{N}$ ?

Comment: Have you tried studying the function a bit, see how it works? Make a drawing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are two arguments.  The first should make the statement "visually obvious" while the second is more formal.

Construct a grid displaying the value of $\phi(n,k)$ for each value of $n$ and $k$:
$$\begin{matrix}
  \color{red}{\phantom{k={}}4}&14\cr
  \color{red}{\phantom{k={}}3}&9&13\cr
  \color{red}{\phantom{k={}}2}&5&8&12\cr
  \color{red}{\phantom{k={}}1}&2&4&7&11\cr
  \color{red}{n=0}&0&1&3&6&10\phantom{=n}\cr
  &\color{blue}{0}&\color{blue}{1}&\color{blue}{2}&\color{blue}{3}&\color{blue}{\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!4\rlap{{}=k}}
\end{matrix}$$
This should make it pretty clear what is going on.  A formal proof could be as follows.

First, suppose that $n_1+k_1>n_2+k_2$.  Since we are talking about integers, this means that $n_1+k_1\ge n_2+k_2+1$ and we have
$$\eqalign{\phi(n_1,k_1)
  &=\tfrac12(n_1+k_1+1)(n_1+k_1)+n_1\cr
  &\ge\tfrac12(n_2+k_2+2)(n_2+k_2+1)+n_1\cr
  &=\tfrac12(n_2+k_2+1)(n_2+k_2)+n_2+k_2+1+n_1\cr
  &>\phi(n_2,k_2)\ .\cr}$$
Now suppose that $\phi(n_1,k_1)=\phi(n_2,k_2)$.  By the above argument we cannot have $n_1+k_1>n_2+k_2$, by a symmetrical argument we cannot have $n_2+k_2>n_1+k_1$, therefore $n_1+k_1=n_2+k_2$.  Hence
$$\eqalign{\phi(n_1,k_1)=\phi(n_2,k_2)\ 
  &\Rightarrow\ \tfrac12(n_1+k_1+1)(n_1+k_1)+n_1=\tfrac12(n_2+k_2+1)(n_2+k_2)+n_2\cr
  &\Rightarrow\ \tfrac12(n_1+k_1+1)(n_1+k_1)+n_1=\tfrac12(n_1+k_1+1)(n_1+k_1)+n_2\cr
  &\Rightarrow\ n_1=n_2\ ,\cr}$$
and so $k_1=k_2$.  Thus $\phi$ is injective.

Comment: Thanks, you really made it obvious for me!

Answer (score 1):

You should *really* make a drawing. The function enumerates the pairs $(n,k)$ in a diagonal manner. Note that $$(0,0)\mapsto 0,(0,1)\mapsto 1,(1,0)\mapsto 2, (0,2)\mapsto 3,(1,1)\mapsto 4,(2,0)\mapsto 5,\ldots$$

Thus, at least empirically, the function is enumerating $\Bbb N\times\Bbb N$ by travesing the $(n,k)$ grid diagonally from the upmost right. Having this in mind, try to produce a proof that this function is in fact a bijection. One way to go is to note how the function behaves when $n+k$ is constant. You can partition $\Bbb N\times\Bbb N$ into the sets $$S[m]=\{(n,k):n+k=m\}$$

and then show that the image of $S[m]$ under your function is the interval (in $\Bbb N$!) $$\left[\binom{m+1}2, \binom {m+2}2-1\right]$$ in increasing order, thus proving your function is a bijection.

This shouldn't prove too difficult since when $n+k=m$ you function sends $(n,k)$ to $\binom{m+1}2 +n$, thus you can let $n$ move and keep $n+k=m$. This increases from $n=0$ to $n=m$; when $$\binom{m+1}2+m=\frac{m^2+3m}2=\binom{m+2}2-1$$

Comment: I just have one more question - where did those binomial coefficients come from?

Comment: @Angelika The number $\binom {n+1}2$ is known as a triangular number for a concrete reason: the sequence goes $1,3,6,10$ and so on, and is the amount of dots one naturally draws when stacking circles into triangles (like in a pool table array). This function uses this, since it must carry out exactly that triangular array. Again, the drawing should help. The first summand (the binomial coefficient) makes the function "start at the right spot" when $n+k$ is fixed, and the second summand moves the diagonal row in the triangular array, while the binomial coefficient remains fixed.

Answer (score 0):

Note that 
$$\begin{align}
\varphi(0, n+k) &= \frac 1 2 (n+k)(n+k+1) \\
&\le \varphi(n,k) \\
&= \frac 1 2 (n+k)(n+k+1) + n \\
&= n + \sum_{i \le (n+k)} i \\
&< \sum_{i \le (n+k+1)} i \\
&= \varphi(0, n+k+1).
\end{align}$$

Suppose $\varphi(a,b) = \varphi(c,d)$. If $a+b < c+d$, then
$$\begin{align}
\varphi(a,b) &< \varphi(0,a+b+1) \\
&\le \varphi(0,c+d) \\
&\le \varphi(c,d), \\
\end{align}$$
so $a+b \ge c+d$. Similarly, $a+b \le c+d$, so $a+b = c+d$. By definition of $\varphi$, we have $a=c$. It follows that 
$$\begin{align}
(a+b)(a+b+1) &= (c+d)(c+d+1) \\
&= c^2 + 2cd + d^2 + c + d \tag{i}\\
&= (c+b)(c+b+1) \\
&= c^2 + 2cb + b^2 + c + b.\tag{ii}
\end{align}$$

Subtracting (ii) from (i),
$$\begin{align}
0 &= (c^2 + 2cd + d^2 + c + d) - (c^2 + 2cb + b^2 + c + b) \\
&= 2c(d-b) + (d^2-b^2) + (d - b) \\
&= 2c(d-b) + (b+d)(d-b) + (d - b) \\
&= (2c+b+d+1)(d-b),\\
\end{align}$$
so $(2c+b+d+1) = 0$ or $(d-b) = 0$. But $(2c+b+d+1) > 0$ as $b,c,d\in \Bbb N$, so we must have $d-b = 0$, which is to say, $b = d$.

Answer (score -1):

It might be easier to start by letting $(n, k)$ be such that $\varphi( \langle n, k\rangle ) = 0$. Then, $(n + k + 1)(n+k) + 2n = 0$, and since $n, k \in \mathbb{N}$, $(n + k + 1)(n + k), 2n \ge 0$, so $2n = n = 0$, so $k = 0$, and since $(n, k) = (0, 0)$, $\varphi$ is injective.

Comment: How do you conclude injectivity?

Comment: Is $0$ an element of $\mathbb{N}$ in this question?

Comment: Indeed, if 0 is or not a natural is not relevant in this question

Comment: It is very relevent in this answer

Comment: How can you conclude injectivity from this? $\varphi$ is not a homomorphism.

Comment: I understand that the kernel of $\varphi$ contains only of $(0,0)$, but actually, how does it show that it is injective?

Comment: If $\varphi$ were a homomorphism, then $0=\phi(a,b)-\phi(c,d)=\phi(a-c,b-d)$ would imply $a=c$ and $b=d$ which would give injectivity. However, I do not think $\varphi$ is a homomorphism in this case (e.g., $\phi(1,1)+\phi(1,1) = 4+4 \ne 12 = \phi(2,2) $), so I do not see how Sam's argument works.

Comment: Is there any other way in which I can show the injectivity then?